# Fancybox: Different url for different popup

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, url, fancybox

I have a page with some box where avery box have a popup (onclick).

My issue is that i need that every popup have a different url.

The site is in php(smarty) and the boxes are generate with a loop.

Someone know if is possible to define a different url for every popup generated?

This is the code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="row_content">
        {assign var=index value=0}
        {foreach from=$case_studies key=myId item=data}
         <div class="news_column">
            <div class="item_news">
                <a title="<b>{$data.case_study_titolo|upper}</b>.<br> {$data.case_study_descrizione}" class="fancybox-effects-c" href="{$data.src_lb}">
                    <img alt="{$data.case_study_titolo} sviluppato per {$data.cliente_titolo} " src="{$data.src_home}">
                    <h1>{$data.case_study_titolo}</h1>
                    <p>{$data.case_study_short}</p>
                    <h2>{$data.categoria_titolo}</h2>
                </a>
            </div>
         </div>
         {assign var=index value=$index+1}
         {if is_int($index/3)}
             <div class="separatore"></div>
         {/if}
        {/foreach}
        <div class='clr' style='height:100px'></div>
        <div style='text-align: center; margin-top: -50px;'>
            <a href='{$smarty.const.URL}progetti'>
                <img src='{$smarty.const.LINK_DEVEYES}images/punti.jpg' alt='dot'>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
            <div class='row_shadow'></div>
            <div class="separatore" style="height: 50px"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
/*
$('.item_news a').click(function unableLink(e) {
    if ($(window).width() < 1034 ) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
 */

$(document).ready(function(){
//         App.init();
//         Gallery.init();
/*
 *  Simple image gallery. Uses default settings
 */

$('.fancybox').fancybox();

/*
 *  Different effects
 */

// Change title type, overlay closing speed
$(".fancybox-effects-a").fancybox({
helpers: {
title : {
type : 'outside'
},
overlay : {
speedOut : 0
}
}
});

// Disable opening and closing animations, change title type
$(".fancybox-effects-b").fancybox({
openEffect  : 'none',
closeEffect : 'none',

helpers : {
title : {
type : 'over'
}
}
});

// Set custom style, close if clicked, change title type and overlay color
$(".fancybox-effects-c").fancybox({
wrapCSS    : 'fancybox-custom',
closeClick : true,

openEffect : 'none',

helpers : {
title : {
type : 'inside'
},
overlay : {
css : {
'background' : 'rgba(118,168,187,0.45)'
}
}
}
});

// Remove padding, set opening and closing animations, close if clicked and disable    overlay
$(".fancybox-effects-d").fancybox({
padding: 0,

openEffect : 'elastic',
openSpeed  : 150,

closeEffect : 'elastic',
closeSpeed  : 150,

closeClick : true,

helpers : {
overlay : null
}
});

/*
*  Button helper. Disable animations, hide close button, change title type and content
*/

$('.fancybox-buttons').fancybox({
openEffect  : 'none',
closeEffect : 'none',

prevEffect : 'none',
nextEffect : 'none',

closeBtn  : false,

helpers : {
title : {
type : 'inside'
},
buttons : {}
},

afterLoad : function() {
this.title = 'Image ' + (this.index + 1) + ' of ' + this.group.length + (this.title ? '     - ' + this.title : '');
}
});


/*
*  Thumbnail helper. Disable animations, hide close button, arrows and slide to next     gallery item if clicked
*/

$('.fancybox-thumbs').fancybox({
prevEffect : 'none',
nextEffect : 'none',

closeBtn  : false,
arrows    : false,
nextClick : true,

helpers : {
thumbs : {
width  : 50,
height : 50
}
}
});

/*
*  Media helper. Group items, disable animations, hide arrows, enable media and button    helpers.
*/
$('.fancybox-media')
.attr('rel', 'media-gallery')
.fancybox({
openEffect : 'none',
closeEffect : 'none',
prevEffect : 'none',
nextEffect : 'none',

arrows : false,
helpers : {
media : {},
buttons : {}
}
});

/*
*  Open manually
*/

$("#fancybox-manual-a").click(function() {
$.fancybox.open('1_b.jpg');
});

$("#fancybox-manual-b").click(function() {
$.fancybox.open({
href : 'iframe.html',
type : 'iframe',
padding : 5
});
});

$("#fancybox-manual-c").click(function() {
$.fancybox.open([
            {
href : '1_b.jpg',
title : 'My title'
}, {
href : '2_b.jpg',
title : '2nd title'
}, {
href : '3_b.jpg'
}
], {
helpers : {
thumbs : {
width: 75,
height: 50
}
}
});
});
}
);
/*
$('a').click(function unableLink(e) {
    if ($(window).width() < 1034 ) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
*/
$('a').click(function () {
if ($(window).width() < 768 ) {
$("#mainmenu2").slideUp('fast');
}
});

</script>
```

Comment: `if is possible to define a different url for every popup generated?` ... could you elaborate? Fancybox will open whatever you have defined in the link's `href`, what you defined there before, is up to your php code, so?

Comment: in my project the popups are open without the change of the url. but now i need that every popup have a different url, maybe like www.xxx.com/#1. <a href='{$smarty.const.URL}progetti'> i think that this link check a content on the db but url doesnt change

Comment: what does `{$data.src_lb}` return then?